# how to click with ng-href and buttontext using Protractor typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I need help on creating a protractor typescript code, how do i click this button? ng-href or href has a dynamic id attached on it, but it has a static buttontext, does anyone have an idea how to do this? code on the site is:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-href="/DriversProfileEdit/?assetGuid=s0s9ff10-3900-4s23-abc6-6865f0d4" 
target="_blank" style="line-height: 1.0" href="/DriversProfileEdit/?assetGuid=s0s9ff10-3900-4s23-abc6-6865f0d4">Driver Profile</a>
```

i've tried the following below, i can't seem to make it work..

```
driverclick = element(by.partialLinkText('DriversProfileEdit'));
driverclick = element(by.css('/DriversProfileEdit/?assetGuid=s0s9ff10-3900-4s23-abc6-6865f0d4'));
driverclick = element(by.partialLinkText('/DriversProfileEdit/?assetGuid='));
driverclick = element(by.cssContainingText('[href*="/DriversProfileEdit/?assetGuid=s0s9ff10-3900-4s23-abc6-6865f0d4"]', 'Driver Profile'));
```

then performed

```
driverclick.click();
```

none of any of those worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If href and ng-href change, you can stick to things that do not change, like class and button text:

```
driverclick = element(by.cssContainingText('a.btn.btn-default','Driver Profile'))
```

Comment: it still does not work. error Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) at doSend.then.response (D:\PROTR_DrivrAT00\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30) at <anonymous> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: by.cssContainingText("a.btn.btn-default", "Driver Profile")

Comment: sorry your suggestion worked. I just forgot to add browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); on my code